# Win10: How bring up VPN from Scheduled Task and/or Command line?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I would like to automate reconnect to VPN when I log in, or when laptop comes out of sleep.

I thought of a scheduled task that runs on login.

But what is the command?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's `rasdial`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614465/establish-a-vpn-connection-in-cmd). For example if you got an L2TP/IPsec connection called "VPN Work" then you can use it as:

```
rasdial "VPN Work" "your-l2tp-username" "your-l2tp-password"
```

To disconnect use:

```
rasdial "VPN Work" /DISCONNECT
```

Comment: I should add that if creds are saved in rasdial, then all you need is: rasdial "VPN Work"   , and that to use a domain cred, the username is: username@domain.com